# How do I stop setup.py from trying to include -arch ppc on MacOSX builds?

Tags: python, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard, setup.py

It appears that Xcode4 doesn't include PPC as a build option anymore.  When using setup.py for modules that include C extensions, setup.py always attempts the build with these options:

`gcc-4.2 ... -DMACOSX -arch i386 -arch ppc ...`

This fails with the error message

```
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
```

If I just remove -arch ppc from the failed command it completes fine and I can rerun `setup.py build` to move on to the next step.

This is okay for modules that only include one C extension, like ssl, but for something like PIL that builds a ton of extensions it is a major pain.

Is there some way to prevent setup.py from including -arch ppc in the compilation parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Remove ppc from compilation flags in python setup scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214133/remove-ppc-from-compilation-flags-in-python-setup-scripts/5808548#5808548)

Or, fix Xcode 4 installation about ppc assembler.

```
$ sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc /Developer/usr/libexec/gcc/darwin
$ sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc /usr/libexec/gcc/darwin
```

Comment: I found the offending line in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/sysconfig.py`